# Javascript Increment function not working

Tags: javascript, increment

I need all 3 console logs to return true. This is the code I have:

```
              var obj = {
                  value: 1,
                  increment: function(obj) {
                    this.value += 1;
                  }
              }
              console.log (obj.increment() == 2);
              console.log (obj.increment() == 3);
              console.log (obj.increment() == 4);
```

I am only allowed to change code inside the increment function. I tried this.value += 1 but this returns "4" for some reason and I cant understand why. This is part of a small exercise and Im stuck on this...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot the `return` statement in `increment()`.

Comment: What the hell, i tried return this.value += 1; earlier and it didnt work, and now all the sudden it does...

Sigh, thanks.

Comment: Yep, been there. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Like Squint said forgot return statement... So nothing wont appear, meaning its neither true or false... It actually needs a value not just a function..

```
var obj = {
                  value: 1,
                  increment: function(obj) {
                    this.value += 1;
                    return this.value;
                  }
              }
              console.log (obj.increment() == 2);
              console.log (obj.increment() == 3);
              console.log (obj.increment() == 4);
```

Now here its returning an actual value... So whats its doing is (basically):

```
console.log(obj.value == 2)
console.log(obj.value == 3)
console.log(obj.value == 4)
```

Then each time as you increment

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, your missing a Return parameter. You declared a variable inside a function but you need to add something like {this.value += 1;return obj;} if you want a true/false returned instead of an index. Which value did you need returned?
 @Dsafds may already have your answer.